# CursorWindowAllocation Exception while using Room DB with Rx

Tags: java, android

I am using `Room database` in android and Query is executed on background thread for which I am using `Rx`. Callback from Rx is returned on either main thread or IO thread based on requirement. But, sometimes `CursorWindowAllocationException` is thrown by `Room`. I am not using cursor directly. It is handled by Room itself. Any help will be appreciated.

I could not try anything because I have no clue about the problem. I have noticed that the problem occurs when there is a large amount of data. But, I am not 100% sure.

```
@Dao
public interface ContentDao {
  @Insert
  long insertContent(ContentModel contentModel);

  @Query("SELECT * FROM " + DBConstant.CONTENT_TABLE)
  List<ContentModel> getContentDetail();
}

Executing Query:

if (isCallbackRequiredOnMainThread) {
      Single.just(1)
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.IO())
          .map(i -> {
            //Executing Query
            return data == null ? nullD : data;
          }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(data -> dDbCallback.onDbDataReceived(data));
    } else {
      Single.just(1)
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.IO())
          .map(i -> {
            //Executing Query
            return data == null ? nullD : data;
          }).subscribe(data -> dDbCallback.onDbDataReceived(data));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was in RxJava's .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) for Flowable responses in RxJava Room adapter. Apparently, it was starting threads but has never released them. You need to increase thread count to apparently, get rid of error

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the reason as far as my own observation is concerned. I have seen this problem even without Rx.